# Solving system of differential equations, checking for stability and plotting the result

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

I am trying to solve the following system, but I am not sure if I am doing it properly

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{\dot{y}} = \mathbf{Ay} \text{ where } \mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
-2    & 1  \\
-1       & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I learned that the solution will have general form:

\begin{equation}
x = \eta e^{r t} 
\end{equation}

where $\eta$ is the eigenvector and $r$ the eigenvalue.

I calculated these using:

$$det(A- r I)\eta = 0$$
the eigenvalues are given by
\begin{equation}
det(A- r I) = 0   \implies r = -1.
\end{equation}

afterwards the eigenvector will be given by: 
$$\left(\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\ -1&0\end{pmatrix}-1\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}\right)\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
...
\end{pmatrix}=0$$
giving:

$ \begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\ -1&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
...
\end{pmatrix}$ next this can be reduced by row echelon to $\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\end{pmatrix}= 0 \implies -x +y =0$ thus x=y

So the final solution would be:

$$x(t) = \begin{pmatrix}y\\ y \end{pmatrix}e^t$$.

Are my solutions correct or is there mistake somewhere? Also, how could I check for stability and plot the graph including the eigenvector the isoclines and some trajectories?

Comment: What is $\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
...
\end{pmatrix}$? You have $2 \times 2$ matrices, so the vectors should have 2 components as well. Also, what are $x,y$? If those are components of the vector function, then what does your last expression mean?

Comment: @YuriyS According to book I am following before you find the eigenvector you should use a general vector that can have n rows and then reduce it. Also, the last expression is hopefully the solution to the system. I should probably have called the vector unknowns $y_1, y_2$

Comment: Your unknown vectors should have 2 rows exactly, because your matrix has 2 columns... The last expression is not consistent with the previous ones, because $x$ is either a number or a vector. And $y$ is still unknown, how is this a solution?

Comment: @YuriyS I am not claiming it is correct solution, that is why I posted the question in the first place.

Comment: @YuriyS I did not edited it after you posted but probably just before also sorry I forgot minus in front of the 2 my bad

Comment: @YuriyS I am not sure to be honest. Could you maybe send me the old solution you posted even though that one step was wrong, maybe I can figure it somehow...

Comment: I think I fixed it. But please, make sure you understand what happens and what methods are used and why. After all, you are studying all this stuff right now, so by default, you should know more than me. Especially since I barely went to my lectures on ODEs and had to search online how to solve this right now ;))

Comment: Of course, checking for stability I leave up to you. If you were given this assignment, you should know how to do that. If not, just search online or read your lectures or a textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original system can be rewritten as:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \dot{y}_1 \\ \dot{y}_2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Where $y_1=y_1(t)$, $y_2=y_2(t)$ are the functions to be found.

Let's consider a general system of linear ODEs with constant coefficients:

$$\dot{\vec{y}}=\hat{A} \vec{y}$$

Indeed, a partial solution to such a system can be expressed through the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a square matrix $\hat{A}$ because:

$$\hat{A} \vec{a}_j=v_j \vec{a}_j$$

$$\vec{y}_j=\vec{a}_j e^{v_j t}$$

Where $\vec{a}_j$ and $v_j$ are eigenvectors and eigenvalues respectively. $j=1,...,n$ where $n$

Using this, we can write:

$$\dot{\vec{y}}_j=v_j\vec{a}_j e^{v_j t}=\hat{A} \vec{a}_j e^{v_j t}=\hat{A}\vec{y}_j$$

We can write the general solution as a combination of partial solutions for all eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

$$\vec{y}(t)=\sum_j^n C_j \vec{a}_j e^{v_j t}$$

For some arbitrary constants $C_j$.

---

Now eigenvalues for small $n$ are indeed found by solving the equation:

$$\det (\hat{A}-v\hat{I})=0$$

In this case the equation becomes:

$$(-2-v)(-v)+1=0 \\ v^2+2v+1=0 \\ (v+1)^2=0 \\ v=-1$$

We get a degenerate case, when the two eigenvalues are the same (repeated eigenvalues).

Because of that, for the general solution we need to take the following two vectors:

$$\vec{y}_1=\vec{a} e^{vt} \\ \vec{y}_2=(\vec{b}+\vec{a} t)e^{vt}$$

Where $\vec{b}$ is the solution of:

$$(\vec{A}-v \vec{I}) \vec{b}=\vec{a}$$

Why can we do that I leave for you to find in your lectures/textbooks.

This leaves us to find the eigenvector $\vec{a}=(a_1,a_2)^T$ for $v=-1$. We need to solve:

$$-2a_1+a_2=-a_1 \\ -a_1=-a_2$$

We get $a_1=c$, $a_2=c$ for some arbitrary constant $c$. Since we are searching for a partial solution we can take $c=1$.

The vector $\vec{b}$ is found from:

$$(-2+1) b_1+b_2=1 \\ -b_1+b_2=1$$

Again, we get multiple solutions, so I think we can choose whatever we want, like:

$$b_1=0 \\ b_2=1$$

The general solution can be expressed as:

> $$\vec{y}(t)=C_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} e^{-t}+C_2 \left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} t \right) e^{-t}$$

For arbitrary constants $C_1,C_2$. We can check if it works by substitution:

$$\dot{\vec{y}}(t)=(C_2-C_1) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} e^{-t}-C_2 \left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} t \right) e^{-t}$$

$$\hat{A} \vec{y}=-C_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} e^{-t}+C_2 \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} t \right) e^{-t}$$

The two expressions after simplification are equal, so our solution is correct.